# Bootstrap theme for Sencha GXT

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, twitter-bootstrap, gxt

I have this GXT 3 based app deployed in Google App Engine (GAE): [Ext GWT Explorer Demo](http://explorer-demo.appspot.com/)

However, I want to know if how can I use the `Twitter Bootstrap` theme on Sencha GXT 3?

GXT 3 is a load of Enterprise-class features,

- Is there a way to use Twitter boostrap with Sencha GXT 3?
- If so, what are the steps to do this

So we can have a cool-looking app 
that use all the added benefits of GXT to GWT.

Adding the POM dependency in a GWT project, I think it comes with the standard GXT css and style.

So from my experience here's what I've tried:

- GXT widgets work, more specifically its "data" functions, but eventually change the CSS as you interact with the widget, from the custom theme (like Bootstrap) into GXT theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the themes designed for Ext with Ext. Ext4.2 and later are shipped with a new theme "Neptune", that looks like Windows 8, which means it is closer to Twitter Bootstrap than the classic Ext theme. And it is way easier to customize too. But apparently, it has not been ported to GXT yet.